# How can I detect small objects with Faster RCNN without increasing the input size?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api

I am using baseline Faster RCNN with an InceptionV2 architecture to detect small objects in a driving scene. All the different parameters I'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config). My input size is `[450, 600, 3]`. When training with this input size, everything works great and the model is able to detect small objects on the test set as intended.

But, in an attempt to reduce inference time I made the input size smaller and changed it to `[225, 300, 3]` and retrained the model. Accuracy went way down on the smaller objects which makes sense because the model has less information to work with.

How can I adjust either FasterRCNN or my training data to be able to increase accuracy when detecting small objects whilst maintaining some medium to high level of accuracy?

Comment: After you rescale your input image to a smaller size, you might need to change the scales in `grid_anchor_generator`(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/c33d3ef4bf37dcd6cb54c033a04a8264a4b64c23/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_cosine_lr_coco.config#L23) to smaller values as well.

Comment: Roger that! I'll try it out and will let you know how it goes :). Ty for your answer.